# Eigenvalues of Block Anti-Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In line with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/79789/79163) answer, I am trying to find the eigenvalues of:

$\mathbf P\mathbf K\mathbf P^\top=\begin{pmatrix}& d_1 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\d_1 &  & e_1 &  &  &  &  &  \\& e_1 &  & d_2 &  &  &  &  \\&  & d_2 &  & e_2 &  &  &  \\&  &  & e_2 &  & d_3 &  &  \\&  &  &  & d_3 &  & e_3 &  \\&  &  &  &  & e_3 &  & d_4 \\&  &  &  &  &  & d_4 & \end{pmatrix}$

which, by the linked post, are the singular values of : $\mathbf B=\begin{pmatrix}d_1&e_1&&\\&d_2&e_2&\\&&d_3&e_3\\&&&d_4\end{pmatrix}$

and $\mathbf K=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf 0&\mathbf B^\top \\\hline \mathbf B&\mathbf 0\end{array}\right)$

All the entries of B are real and positive. I do not know the eigenvectors of $\mathbf P\mathbf K\mathbf P^\top$. I am trying to show that the eigenvalues of the matrix (shown below) are natural numbers (disregarding sign).

However, from another incredibly insightful post of J.M.'s, if we can find a Cholesky factorization of the matrix below, then we can put the factorization in block form:

$\mathbf K=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf 0&\mathbf B^\top \\\hline \mathbf B&\mathbf 0\end{array}\right)$

And then there exist a similar matrix $\bf H$ to $\bf K$ such that $\bf H$ is closely related to Golub-Kahan tridiagonal matrix (which has known and nice eigenvalues).

My current efforts are focused around trying to find a nice Cholesky factorization of $\mathbf P\mathbf K\mathbf P^\top$.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Edit: I consider even-order matrices. One such example is the matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 &0 \\ 
3\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 & 3\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} & 0\\ 
0& 3\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 & 3 \sqrt{6}\\ 
 0& 0 & 3 \sqrt{6} &0 
\end{pmatrix}$
with eigenvalues $-9,9,-3,3$

so that $\bf{ B} = \begin{pmatrix}
3\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 3\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\\ 
0 & 3\sqrt{6}
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: What exactly does your bidiagonal matrix look like?

Comment: I have (n=3)* : $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sqrt{5} & 0\\ 
\sqrt{5} & 0 &\sqrt{10} \\ 
0& \sqrt{10} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ Which has eigenvalues $\mp \sqrt{15}$ and $0$ But I also have several other conjectures of this sort, some with nastier square-roots. I am looking for a more general approach in the general setting (size nxn)

Comment: Oh, I forgot. I then have that: $\bf B = \begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{5} & \sqrt{10}\\ 
 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: ...as I had mentioned in that other answer, the Golub-Kahan shuffle works only for *even*-order tridiagonals; you need to deflate the additional zero eigenvalue for odd-order matrices before reformulating as a singular value problem.

Comment: I must have missed that point, although it makes sense as to the necessity of even-orderness. I edited my question to work with the even-order assumption, thanks!

Comment: One last thing I want to point out is that the eigenvalues of the matrix in my second edit are but a conjecture ( for arbitrary size). My aim is to find a way to show the former.