# Distance matrix of connected graph always invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I know there's a question elsewhere about distance matrix for points on Euclidean plane, but I'm not sure if that one was relevant.

Anyway, given a connected (simple) graph G with $n$ vertices $v_1,...,v_n$, the distance matrix is a $n \times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is the distance between $v_i$ and $v_j$ (note: this is NOT the adjacency matrix!). The distance of a vertex to itself is taken to be $0$.

So I know that the matrix is real symmetric and hence diagonalizable. However, I was wondering if $0$ is ever an eigenvalue. That is, is the distance matrix always invertible?

Comment: Consider the cycle graph on 4 vertices.

Comment: It is invertible when $G$ is a tree though.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379574900317

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79779/properties-of-zero-diagonal-symmetric-matrices